# How to Create array object by two dimension loop in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops, associative-array

i have inputs and two select created by button clicked with increment id like 
id="commodity0",id="commodity1",id="commodity2"

i want to send all data in one array contains 
part of id (like "commodity") of input as a sub main array and this array contains nested array inside it the number of rest input id

general concept like below

```
data = [
     commodity = [
         "0" : " value "
         "1" : " value "
         "2" : " value "
     ],
     price = [
         "0" : " value "
         "1" : " value "
         "2" : " value "
     ],
]
```

my code i want to execute this

```
var arr = ['commodity','price','packages_count','packages_type','gross_weight','net_weight','gunit','nunit'];
var data = [];
for (var n in arr){
    model.find('input[id*='+ arr[n] +'] , select[id*='+ arr[n] +']').each(function () {

        var key = $(this).attr('id').match(/[0-9]+/)[0];
        var val = $(this).val();

       **--thanks for complete code from here** 

    });
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the Array that you gave (as expectation) is not a valid JavaScript array. Anyway try something like this, maybe that's what you want:

```
    var arr = ['commodity','price','packages_count','packages_type','gross_weight','net_weight','gunit','nunit'];
    var data = [];
    for (var n in arr){
        var temp = [];
        model.find('input[id*='+ arr[n] +'] , select[id*='+ arr[n] +']').each(function (){

            var key = $(this).attr('id').match(/[0-9]+/)[0];
            var val = $(this).val();
            temp.push({[key]:val});


        });
        data[n] = temp;
    }
```

Comment: thanks bro for reply
but it not work as expected

if logic of my code wrong or ةy way of thinking about this is wrong
Please help

Comment: @MohamedElboraey you have to give us more information, what did you try, what did you get etc. otherwise we can not help you!